# Meta-content or time-datetime

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, meta-tags, dates

How to show `datePublished` and `dateModified` Microdata?
(I want to prioritize `dateModified`, this is why I do not show `datePublished` to the public)

Option 1. If I understand this is not correct. Div cannot have content, right?

```
<div itemprop="datePublished" content="2016-01-07"></div>
<div itemprop="dateModified" content="2016-08-17">Last Updated: 2016-01-07</div>
```

Option 2

```
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2016-01-07">
<meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2016-08-17"><div>Last updated: 2016-01-07</div>
```

Option 3

```
<time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2016-01-07"></time>
<time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="2016-08-17">Last updated: 2016-01-07</time>
```

Question 1: Should I use `meta`, `time`, or both are correct?
Question 2: Should I separate "Last update" and put it in another `div` before `meta` or `time`?

```
<div>Last updated:</div>
<meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2016-08-17">
<div>2016-01-07</div> 

<div>Last Updated: </div>
<time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="2016-08-17">2016-01-07</time>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want it to be visible, use `meta`.
If you want it to be visible, use `time`.

```html
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2016-01-07">
Last updated: <time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="2016-08-17">2016-01-07</time>
```

---

The `div` elements don’t affect the Microdata (unless they have Microdata attributes themselves, of course).

Option 3: While it’s technically possible to use an empty `time` element instead of a `meta` element, having empty elements is typically not a good practice. The `meta` element (and `link` for URIs) can be used for Microdata exactly for this purpose.

Option 2: It’s of course also possible to use `meta` and duplicate the content to make it visible, but this is also not a good practice. Why duplicate something if there is a way to prevent it?

Option 1: Yes, [it’s invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669).